# Issue with Group by clause in linq to sql

Tags: linq

I want to make this query in  `linq` to  `sql` .
Please help. I am new to  `linq` and having problem to with the  `group by clause` .

Here is the  `sql query`

```
select count(USERID), d.DEPTNAME from USERS u
join department d on u.DEPTID = d.DEPTID
group by u.DEPTID, d.DEPTNAME
```

Comment: What have you tried? [SO] is not a code writing service, but we will help you solve problems when you get stuck. (Suggestion: start with a join in LINQ: forget about the aggregate and grouping until you have the base data.)

Comment: ok fine. How i can i achieve group by clause in linq to sql. I am writing the query now I want to count the emp by grouping deptid
var Query = (from u in db.USERS
                 join d in db.DEPARTMENTs on u.DEPTID equals d.DEPTID
                 select u.USERID).Count();

Comment: I think you you need a better tutorial: `group expr by expr` is part of the comprehension syntax, and then there are the numerous overloads of [`Queryable.GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct translation would be like this:

```
var query =
    from u in db.Users
    join d in db.Departments on u.DeptId equals d.DeptId
    group d by new { d.DeptId, d.DeptName } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.DeptName,
        Count = g.Count(),
    };
```

Though I think it would be better off written like this:

```
// looks like we're counting users in each department
var query =
    from d in db.Departments
    select new
    {
        d.DeptName,
        Count = db.Users.Count(u => u.DeptId == d.DeptId),
    };
```